# How do I install the game eggnog (without using wine)?

Tags: tar

Here is where the game's files can be found: http://madgarden.net/junkz/files/eggnogg.
I tried following the instructions here:[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) to install eggnog, but I could find an install file. How do I install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the game does not require installation.

1. Extract the `eggnogg-linux.tar.gz`
2. Open `eggnogg-linux` directory
3. Right-click on `eggnogg` > `Properties` > `Permissions` > Check `Allow executing file as program`

And it should run when double-clicked.

Comment: Additionally, since the game doesnt package it - some people might need to install SDL2 manually. E.g. `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0` (you can use tab-completion to see what packages are available for your system).